# Using AsyncTask to run htttp requests on interval in Android

Tags: java, android, post, android-asynctask, httprequest

I am trying to run a method every an interval which performs a POST request to the server but it fails right in execution with this error message: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, which as I understood is about running a network function in the main thread, however, i have no idea to implement AsyncTask in my case to run this method every given interval.

```
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        renewTrackerList();
        handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
    }
};

 private String renewTrackerList() {
    String _uri = this.website + "page.php?";
    String strResp = "";
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    String strJson = "";

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("token", this.token.trim());
        strJson = json.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, strJson);
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(_uri).post(body).build();

    try {
        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `new Thread(new Runnable() ... ).start()`?

Comment: @EasyJoinDev just tried it and it doesnt make any difference, same error!

Comment: @EasyJoinDev btw it shows an error in .start() . I am not able to write that command

Comment: @EasyJoinDev can you help by posting an answer using my code?

Comment: My suggestion is to instantiate the Thread inside a method of your Activity so you can better log the errors. To get more help you have to post the complete code and the error log.